# Bower "Git not in the PATH" error

Tags: javascript, git, node.js

I just installed git and bower via NPM for a project. It's a first time use.

Then I tried running `bower install jQuery` for example, I get this specific error:

`ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH`

Where can I actually define paths and how, and when we say PATHs, what's the main idea?

Also, I really need help with some good resources for learning the concept behind this question or learning NPM usage in general.

I'm using windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: Which OS do you use? Can do you launch the `git` command in the terminal? If not, please install it.

Comment: Sorry. I just made an edit.

Comment: I had the same problem + angularjs is not defined and other too. Installing msysgit bower install jQuery solved the problem. Now I'm happy :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bower : ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path)

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou Apparently, this question was asked in Nov '13 and the link you posted says the question was asked in Dec '13. I think that link is the duplicate.

Comment: @BizDev: The SO review platform does not distinguish based on post date, but I think it uses the voting mechanics instead. The comment is auto posted by the review page

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Install [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/), as stated in [the Bower documentation](https://github.com/bower/bower#a-note-for-windows-users):

> To use Bower on Windows, you must install msysgit correctly. Be sure to check the option shown below:
>
> [ ] Use Git bash only
>
> [x] Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt
>
> [ ] Run Git and included Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt

After the installation has completed, restart CMD. You (and bower) will then be able to run `git` from the command prompt, which will fix your issue.

Comment: Re-installed the msygit using the given setting. Thanks. I'm still having the same error though, where can I define paths and how?

Comment: Tried to logout or reboot?

Comment: Cmd prompt must be restarted after the PATH update. logout/reboot is not required.

Comment: This is possible without msysgit - it's just an issue with your PATH var. See my answer below.

Comment: But why does bower need git in the first place? (No answer here addresses this question...)

Comment: @KunalKapadia You're right. Just restarting CMD is enough after isntalling GIT. No need of restating the whole machine. Cheers !

Answer (score 7):

Make sure u installed git with 2nd or 3rd option selected from list.
It will penetrate git command to cmd by modifying PATH automatically ;)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Manual method is to add the Git `cmd` path to your windows `PATH` environment variable. The Git cmd path will be unique on your machine, and something like:

`C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<SomeGuid>\cmd\`

From command prompt, add it to your PATH var like so:

`path C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<SomeGuid>\cmd\;%PATH%`

Answer (score 1):

Install Bower using Git Bash and run **bower install jQuery** from Git Bash. Git doesn't work from Windows command prompt as **CMD** is not POSIX compatible.

Comment: you are mistaken. it does work from the cmd prompt.

npm -g install bower
install msysGit while selecting [command prompt]
bower install reqwest

Answer (score 1):

Forget powershell and command prompt. Use git bash and it works like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the "Git bash" in that directory but not the command terminal of the system:like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First install git on your pc, if you do not add the path then add it yourself

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd