# Bower: ENOGIT Git is not installed or not in the PATH

Tags: javascript, git, bower

Git is installed and is in the path.

Platform: [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 5.8.

```
>which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

Yet bower can't find it:

```
bower angular#1.0.6  ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

What is the recommended work-around?

Comment: This boiled down to a problem with node-which. If a file is in the path but has suid/sguid set, node-which will not 'see' it.  In my case, git was in the path, and unix which found it. the pemissions were set like this: -rwxrwsr--   1 root mygroup.  When I ran chmod 755 git. which.sync('git') found it.

Comment: This issue is also applicable to windows 7 and so are the solutions e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path/21444065#21444065 solution works

Comment: @PeterMortensen You linked the wrong OS. "Red Hat Linux" is an obsolete product from 20 years ago. "Red Hat **Enterprise** Linux" is the name of the thing being used in this century.

Comment: I ran into this on Ubuntu 15.10, and I fixed it "perhaps" by installing git and then AFTER git is installed, fully un-install and then re-install npm, and then proceed with all install steps following the "install npm" step, and it seemed to work, although too two runs(attempts at same command) to succeed, if a recall. There must be some reconfigure all command for npm or something what would allow it to rebuild locations of git, etc. BTW: The place this halted my forward progress was trying to install the Polymer/polymer package.

Comment: Why we can't just install Git with bower then ?

Comment: I had this problem in Windows 10 because my %GIT_HOME% variable had quotes in it: `GIT_HOME="C:\Program Files\Git"`. Changing it to `GIT_HOME=C:\Program Files\Git` fixed the issue.

Comment: I do not need git. I just need to do this > `bower install --save bootstrap-css`. But it needs git. What a mess.

Answer (score 341):

Adding Git to Windows 7/8/8.1 Path

Note: You must have **[msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/)** installed on your machine. Also, the path to my Git installation is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git". Yours might be different. Please check where yours is before continuing.

Open the Windows Environment Variables/Path Window.

1. Right-click on *My Computer* -> *Properties*
2. Click *Advanced System Settings* link from the left side column
3. Click *Environment Variables* in the bottom of the window
4. Then under *System Variables* look for the path variable and click edit
5. Add the pwd to Git's binary and cmd at the end of the string like this:

   ```
   ;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\bin;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\cmd
   ```

Now test it out in PowerShell. Type `git` and see if it recognizes the command.

[image: This is image showing you how to do so!]

Source: *[Adding Git to Windows 7 Path](http://www.chambaud.com/2013/07/08/adding-git-to-path-when-using-github-for-windows/)*

Comment: This one works very well, I met the problem for installing angularjs tutorial in my IDE (Webstorm). Just have to restart it!

Comment: @eyad-farra : please mark verified for [Johnathan Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path#21444065) posted answer if solves your problem. Else, try to proceed with some response as other people are also waiting for your response so that they can avoid redundancy in posting same issue.

Comment: After you do this you need to open a new cmd as well ... if you have an existing shell open it won't have the path included.

Comment: Works in Windows 8.1 too

Comment: If you're using SourceTree try adding `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: it will not work if you have not installed on c: drive

Comment: `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%` did not work for me, but `C:\Program Files (x86)` did. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: Every thing's ok but after installing Git a windows restart is needed.

Comment: `;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` worked for me !!

Comment: Please, edit your answer and add @Vojtik's remark: cmd prompt must be restarted after the PATH update, because it can save people a lot of time :)

Comment: @Vojtiik. I beg to differ a little. NOT just the command prompt but the SYSTEM must be restarted for changes to take effect. Oh ! I am on windows 7. Not sure about the win8

Comment: Why all answers are for Windows if the question was explicitly for Linux?

Comment: And windows 10 too, just validate first if is C:\Program Files\Git\bin and not something else.

Answer (score 219):

Just use the Git Bash instead of cmd.

Comment: Why is that? Anyway this fixed my issue with bower. I ran "bower install" through "Git Shell" (cygwin would also work) on Windows 7 and it worked, where the Node.js command prompt failed.

Comment: For the most part, this is a correct answer. However, [some extensions](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/65748cdb-4087-497e-a394-2e3449c8e61e) will depend on cmd, rather than bash, and will need git in the path of cmd.

Comment: This is the simplest solution and works. "Git Bash" is called "Git Shell" in Windows. This works possibly because novice people prefer to use the first option when installing git.

Comment: used Git Bash instead of Powershell as well.

Answer (score 71):

Run the following command at your node.js command prompt where "<git path>" is the path to your git bin folder:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<git path>;
```

So, like this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
```

Or this: (Notice the (x86) )

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
```

This will add git to your path variables. Be sure you type it correctly or you could possibly delete your path vars which would be bad.

Comment: You may also need add %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\cmd to the path, ej: set PATH=%PATH%;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\bin;%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Git\cmd

Comment: exit your cmd window and start a new one after PATH change. I had to do that after installing msysgit for cmd to pick up new PATH value.

Comment: Simple and Clean solution. WOW

Answer (score 27):

Make sure you installed Git with the second or third option selected from the list. It will penetrate the Git command to cmd by modifying PATH automatically ;)

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for the option 2.Not sure about option 3. Adding a path variable manually only does and reflects the true state after a restart.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error in Windows. Adding git to the path fixed the issue.

```
G:\Dropbox\Development\xampp\htdocs.penfolds.git\penfolds-atg-development>bower install
bower bootstrap#~3.0.0          ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH

G:\>PATH
PATH=E:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;

G:\Dropbox\Development\xampp\htdocs.penfolds.git\penfolds-atg-development>set PATH=%PATH%;E:\Program Files\Git\bin;

G:\Dropbox\Development\xampp\htdocs.penfolds.git\penfolds-atg-development>bower install
bower bootstrap#~3.0.0      not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.0.0
bower bootstrap#~3.0.0         resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.0.0
```

Comment: that indeed seems to work, but it's very odd that it doesn't work the other way(adding git to the %PATH% environment variables.

Comment: You need to restart your command prompt window for the modified environment variables to used.

Comment: adding git to PATH resolves it, even on built-in Command as well as NodeJS based Command.

Answer (score 14):

On Windows, you can try to set the path at the command prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in windows, but sometimes Git bin path may different like C:\Users\Isuru\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin

Comment: Worked for me on windows Intellij Idea

Answer (score 13):

I am also getting the same error and the solution is first to check if the **Git** is installed or not in the system and if not please install it.

After installation, open **Git Bash** or **Git Shell** from Windows and go to your project (same way you go in command prompt using "cd path"). **Git Shell** is installed by default with **Github** windows installation.

Then run the same **bower install** command. It will work as expected.

The below screenshot shows the command using **Git Shell**
[image: Bower install using Git Shell]

Comment: This works for me. I used Git Shell that is installed when I install Github desktop.

Answer (score 7):

When you ran the git install, you probably didn't choose:

"Use Git from the Windows Command Prompts"

during the installation.

Re-run git install, and choose that option.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the ENVIRONMENT PATH. Follow these steps:

1. Search for 'Edit the system environment variables'.
2. Click on 'Environment Variables'.
3. In the 'System variables' section, scroll down and click on the variable 'Path'. Click 'Edit'.
4. Append this text to the end of the 'Variable value'.

> ;%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin;%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\cmd

Answer (score 3):

I also got the same problem from cmd and resolved using the following steps.

First install the https://msysgit.github.io/ (if not alredy installed).
Then set the Git path as suggested by skinneejoe:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
```

Or this (notice the (x86)):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux:

if you dont have installed git use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

with command `which git` you will know the directory where is and then add in path if it is not in that enviroment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this problem on a cPanel **CentOS 6** linux machine.
The solution for me was to symlink the cPanel git to **/usr/local/bin/git**

```
ln -s /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/git /usr/local/bin/git
```

Comment: This fix worked for me, run as root, allows all lower users to access git properly

Answer (score 0):

1.Set the Path of Git in environment variables.
2.From Windows command prompt,
run cd Project\folder\Path\
run the command: bower install

Answer (score 0):

People above already gave solutions for your proplem, I hope so. If someone is facing this issue in 2022 in using docker images, then you should add a command to install git in your image.

For Example you are using **alpine** image in your `Dockerfile`. Then it will be something like this :

```
FROM node:8.3-alpine

# ....... other stuffs .....

RUN apk add git


# ....... other stuffs .....
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by install Git Bash from [Download Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Setting this option 3 when installing the software as shown bellow.

[image: Setting Path variable]

Finally select the project folder by right click using Bash as shown below.

[image]

and type

> npm install

. It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

`npm install` from *git bash* did work for me.
 After rebooting PC.

Answer (score -3):

Just use the Git Bash instead of node.js or command prompt

As an Example for installing ReactJS, after opening Git Bash, execute the following command to install react:

```
bower install --react
```

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem and needed to restart the cmd - and the problem goes away.