# Bower can only see git path on gitBash, not in cmd (windows)

Tags: windows, git, bower

Apologies if this is wrong format of question: my issue is resolved in another post but I'm hoping for help on understanding the *why*.

I've been trying to run

```
bower install
```

through the command line as administrator on Windows 8, and I get the error

```
bower ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

However, other "git..." commands in the same window work fine (Git's /bin/ and /cmd/ have been added manually to the system-level path). As per the helpful suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21444065/4477927 , running `bower install` at the same location through git bash - rather than windows cmd - works fine.

So although my problem is solved I'd like to improve my understanding of the tools by knowing why the git command works when typed manually, and can be invoked by bower through git bash, but cant be invoked by bower through cmd?