# I am having error at polymer installation by bower

Tags: polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I am having error at polymer installation by bower. 
when I am install polymer using bower I've got below message and I can't move forword. I've installed git in path already.

```
bower ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

Please Help me for find out, I am just newbie.

Comment: repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you don't have GIT installed. Bower needs GIT installed on your system so it can download repositories. If you do have it installed it could be that you don't have it listed on your PATH (System properties, system variables).

Comment: But I am using git for my version control

Comment: How may I get continue?

Comment: If you do have the GIT client installed and you still have that error check that GIT is in your PATH environment variable. If you are on windows follow the instructions here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm