# 'Git not installed or path not specified' while installing bower components even after having git & the path variables as given in stackoverflow

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, bower

Im working on a project that requires bower components from Git and its not being installed even after i having GIT in my system. I have also set the path to git/cmd.

The configs are : Windows7; GIT is 2.7.0.windows1 and the Path is programfiles/git/cmd

I have also tried the various solutions given here in Stackoverflow but nothing solved my problem. One interesting observation i made is there was no git in user/appdata

npm is also installed in the system. Kindly suggest me a solution to this issue.

[git not in the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVBbl.jpg)
,
[the git terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0km3.jpg)

Comment: "In my system"? Which system? Which OS? which git version is installed? What is your $PATH (or %PATH% on Windows) ?

Comment: @VonC; thanks for pointing out that i was vauge. Windows7; version of git is 2.7.0.windows1 and the Path is programfiles/git/cmd

Comment: Does your user path has the git path in it, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23179102/6309?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower clearly states in its "[Windows Users](https://github.com/bower/bower#windows-users)" section:

> To use Bower on Windows, you must install [Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) correctly. Be sure to check the options shown below:

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/10702007/10532690/d2e8991a-7386-11e5-9a57-613c7f92e84e.png]

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/10702007/10532694/dbe8857a-7386-11e5-9bd0-367e97644403.png]

[This issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/972#issuecomment-51186740) confirms it:

> I've encountered the same issue before,
>   I just re-install everything and followed [these instructions](https://github.com/bower/bower#windows-users).
>
> Firstly I installed Git then install bower , it fixes my problem.

Or, at the very least, before your bower command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
```

Comment: I reistalled the whole GIT and now its working. But wonder why such a problem would occur.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem.. and after searching and trying out some answers given by many here in stackoverflow and youtube.. this one thing worked for me on windows..

1. I reinstalled Git.. then..[check the third option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQqlc.png)
2. after installing.. right click on your project folder and select "Git Bash Here".. and it worked like a charm..
3. check also with window cmd.. and it finds Git PATH..

hope this helps.