# npm install web3 Install fails： undefined ls-remote

Tags: node.js, installation, web3js

Installation Environment

**win7 64bit**

I:\nodejs>node -v

**v10.13.0**

I:\nodejs>npm -v

**6.4.1**

I:\nodejs>npm install web3

```
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your appli
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-11T09_18_45_834Z-debug.log
```

I have never encountered such a problem, and I have not found any clues on google.

Answer (score 25):

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
```

Those lines tells you that the problem is the missing `git`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path#23179102) is your solution.

Answer (score 6):

Just install the git your problem will be solve. npm try to download using git

Answer (score 2):

If you have git installed then make sure it's accessible globally by just typing `git` in command prompt.

If you don't see list of git commands then you have to configure your GIT path in windows under `environment variable` section.

[Check this for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666989/bower-enogit-git-is-not-installed-or-not-in-the-path#23179102)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

**step1  npm install --global --production windows-build-tools**

**step2  npm install --global node-gyp**

Answer (score 1):

If this thing happened inside your docker container, you can fix it by adding the following lines to you *Dockerfile*

```
RUN apk add --no-cache git
```

**Source:** https://medium.com/anna-coding/solution-for-npm-err-enoent-undefined-ls-remote-h-t-18ab6f8274af

Answer (score 0):

`undefined ls-remote -h -t git...` can occure if you try to install node modules in windows power shell. Try using git bash instead