# angularjs remove index.html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iis, iis-express

**UPDATE**

AngularJS works now. Switched to WebStorm IDE, but also had problem setting it up, that helped me: [Bower "Git not in the PATH" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069297/bower-git-not-in-the-path-error) (Bower “Git not in the PATH” error).

Soon I will try ngrouting under WebStorm again.

How can I remove index.html from my localhost URL? There are similar questions, but they couldn't help me.

Here is what I did so far:

**index.html:**

```
<head><title>MyApp</title></head>    
<body>
  <div ng-view>
      <a href="#/menu">Menu</a>
      <a href="#/main">Main</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',
  'HTML5ModeURLs'
});
```

**config.js:**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $route.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.
        when('/menu', {
            templateUrl: 'Modules/Menu/view.html',
            controller: 'Modules/Menu/controller'
        }).
        when('/main', {
            templateUrl: 'Modules/Main/view.html',
            controller: 'Modules/Main/controller'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/menu'
        });
}
]);
```

Comment: This is something that can be done server side only, which kind of server are you using ? (Apache / node.js...)

Comment: I am using IIS Express.

Answer (score 2):

You try to remove index.html from your app url ?

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$route.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.
     when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }).
    when('/menu', {
        templateUrl: 'Modules/Menu/view.html',
        controller: 'Modules/Menu/controller'
    }).
    when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'Modules/Main/view.html',
        controller: 'Modules/Main/controller'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/menu'
    });
  }
]);
```

**Setting the route '/' should do the job I guess**. That's how I do it anyway.

Comment: Just in case : did you set the <base href="/"> in the document <head> (for html5Mode) ?

Comment: I set that. Seems like Visual Studio is not detecting AngularJS. (see my updated question). Of course I have ng-app="myApp" in the 'htm'l tag.

Answer (score 2):

You are using IIS Express to host your AngularJS application files, so I think this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode) was what you were looking for. *Yagiz Ozturk* solution suggests you to configure your IIS server this way to rewrite URL, so you will be able to skip the *index.html* part :

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Put that in my web config. Still got http://localhost:10203/App/index.html, http://localhost:10203/App/index.html#/menu, http://localhost:10203/App/index.html#/main as url's. I also installed  url rewriter for iis on server and added a base href to index.html.  Getting a 'Owin' error, when I remove the # from the href's, but Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure is installed and references are made.

Comment: application servererror, "Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5"  could not be found. The System cannot found the file error.