# Bower packages don't install

Tags: bower, bower-install

I am trying to install bower packages, in the site of bower is written I must install them following way:

```
bower install <package>
```

But it doesn't want to install this kinda way. Instead,it tells me something like:

```
ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

How to deal with this kinda problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069297/bower-git-not-in-the-path-error.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install git, some package in bower depend on git to be installed